# C# WPF Sort Numbers

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, numbers

I'm doing a project that consists of a lottery number generator which then saves to a `txt` file, but I have a problem: how can I sort the numbers in ascending order, when each number is in a different label?

**Code**

```
static Random Gerar = new Random();
    public static readonly string FilePath = "ChavesEuromilhões.txt";

    public GerarChave()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void gerarNumeros() // method to generate numbers
    {

        int a = Gerar.Next(1, 50);
        int b = Gerar.Next(1, 50);
        int c = Gerar.Next(1, 50);
        int d = Gerar.Next(1, 50);
        int e = Gerar.Next(1, 50);
        int f = Gerar.Next(1, 12);
        int g = Gerar.Next(1, 12);

        num1.Content = a.ToString();
        num2.Content = b.ToString();
        num3.Content = c.ToString();
        num4.Content = d.ToString();
        num5.Content = e.ToString();
        num6.Content = f.ToString();
        num7.Content = g.ToString();


    }

    private void button_voltar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow sw = new MainWindow();
        sw.Show();
        this.Close();

    }

    private void button_Guardar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //  save the number
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(GerarChave.FilePath, true))
        {
            if (num1.Content == null || num2.Content == null || num3.Content == null || num4.Content == null || num5.Content == null || num6.Content == null || num7.Content == null || comboBox.SelectedValue == null || Date_Picker.SelectedDate == null)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Todos Os campos São de Prenchimento Obrigatorio!");
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteLine(num1.Content + "," + num2.Content + "," + num3.Content + "," + num4.Content + "," + num5.Content + "," + num6.Content + "," + num7.Content + "," + comboBox.SelectedValue + "," + Date_Picker.SelectedDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString());                   
                writer.Close();
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Chave Guardada!");
            }

        }
    }

    private void button_ordenar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {

       // button to order the numbers
     }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: put num1.Conetent though num7.Content into a list and use linq

Comment: Add the numbers to a List and then call `Sort()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could for example store the integers in a `List<int>` that you simply call `Sort` on, e.g.:

```
private readonly List<int> theNumbers = new List<int>();
private void gerarNumeros() // method to generate numbers
{
    int a = Gerar.Next(1, 50);
    int b = Gerar.Next(1, 50);
    int c = Gerar.Next(1, 50);
    int d = Gerar.Next(1, 50);
    int e = Gerar.Next(1, 50);
    int f = Gerar.Next(1, 12);
    int g = Gerar.Next(1, 12);

    theNumbers.Clear();
    theNumbers.Add(a);
    theNumbers.Add(b);
    theNumbers.Add(c);
    theNumbers.Add(d);
    theNumbers.Add(e);
    theNumbers.Add(f);
    theNumbers.Add(g);
    theNumbers.Sort();

    num1.Content = a.ToString();
    num2.Content = b.ToString();
    num3.Content = c.ToString();
    num4.Content = d.ToString();
    num5.Content = e.ToString();
    num6.Content = f.ToString();
    num7.Content = g.ToString();
}

private void button_ordenar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (theNumbers.Count == 7)
    {
        num1.Content = theNumbers[0];
        num2.Content = theNumbers[1];
        num3.Content = theNumbers[2];
        num4.Content = theNumbers[3];
        num5.Content = theNumbers[4];
        num6.Content = theNumbers[5];
        num7.Content = theNumbers[6];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you That Works Great!! :)